# Low-traffic network retransmissions and fails

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I have an local network with generally very low traffic. On the network I have oscilloscope with LAN access, which I want to interrogate. When downloading samples (which come in blocks of a few hundred bytes or so), there are no problems. When I send short commands - say 10 characters, I reliably get a re-transmission on each try. Here's typical cycle:

```
  1 0.000000       192.168.9.101         192.168.9.120         TCP      74     41150→3000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3989588297 TSecr=0 WS=128
  2 0.004792       192.168.9.120         192.168.9.101         TCP      60     3000→41150 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=2144 Len=0 MSS=536
  3 0.004872       192.168.9.101         192.168.9.120         TCP      54     41150→3000 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=0
  4 0.305396       192.168.9.101         192.168.9.120         TCP      66     41150→3000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=12
  5 0.524024       192.168.9.101         192.168.9.120         TCP      66     [TCP Retransmission] 41150→3000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=12
  6 0.536186       192.168.9.120         192.168.9.101         TCP      60     3000→41150 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=13 Win=2132 Len=0
  7 5.323187       192.168.9.101         192.168.9.120         TCP      54     41150→3000 [FIN, ACK] Seq=13 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=0
```

This causes a timeout and a failed command. As can be seen, there is no answer from the 'scope...
I'm suspecting some kind of configuration error, but can't pinpoint where but then I'm not a network expert either. I replaced the cable to be sure... There's also switch in the path, but never gave issues, and other traffic passes ok.

The program sending the commands is a simple Python program. The command seems correct, and a closed-source manufacturer's app works fine when I enter commands manually (running under Wine).

Can anyone suggest where to look?

**Extra:** Thanks, Steffen. That was fast... I doubt packets are really lost. The list above is at the client (i.e. the sender of the command). I'm rather suspecting that the scope is taking too long to decode the command and causes a timeout not ACK-ing in time, and I was reading that a typical RTO would be seconds, but the program is retransmitting after 0.22". Is this ok?

**Nota2:** Partially solved the problem of the communication: The Owon 'scope needs to switch between a 'fast' mode for data transfer and an SCPI mode for remote control. It seems I had forgotten to call the switch function. This does not explain the re-transmissions though. The switching defeats

Comment: You would need to make packet captures at various places on the network to find out where the packets actually get lost. Start with one directly at the client and one as near as possible to the server. Only when you know where the packet gets lost on the path you can determine why it got lost which is needed to fix the problem. Also don't just check for TCP but also ARP packets - sometimes missing or blocked ARP replies might lead to such problems.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, thanks, I replied in the original question as this seems relevant.

Comment: Usually TCP stacks are implemented in the kernel and are independent of the application, i.e. the ACK happens even before the application processes the data. This might be different for this device, i.e. small embedded devices might use single-purpose applications with an embedded TCP stack. Impossible to tell from the outside. But unless one can prove by checking directly before the device that the cause is the device itself and no packet loss, I would not be sure about this theory. but if this would be the case then there is likely nothing you can do about it.

Comment: *But unless one can prove by checking directly before the device* - I can't see how to test it near the device. I have no access to a dedicated network analyzer. I'd like to test my theory, but I can't find any way to set a minimum RTO explicitly (even though there seems to be an RFC (6298) which specifies a 1 second minimum.